# Reverse string by 2 pair in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, reverse

Reversing in 2 pairs means for example: we have a string "helloworld" we need to output in a way that it returns "ehllworodl". We can see that each pair it reverse and concatenated for output.

Comment: The title is certainly not self-explanatory, and honestly, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
            string input = "helloworld";
            string output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                output += input[i + 1];
                output += input[i];
            }
```

Comment: This only works if your character count is even.  If your string happened to be "helloworl", the "l" would be left out.

Comment: @Vahlkron it will definitely works. because of the condition `i < input.Length - 1`. the `-1` means leave the last character. `"helloworl".Length` will be `9`. therefore `i` will be 8 and its end of the loop. because `8 < 9 - 1` would be false. please dont downvote a correct answer

Comment: OP asks for a program to reverse a string by pairs of characters, jdweng provides exactly that.  A string of odd count letters was undefined in the question, so I think it's fine that it be undefined in the answer also.  Maybe the OP should move it alone as though it were paired with a blank or maybe he could throw an exception.  But it was not up to jdweng to guess.