# How to reverse a string 2character and 2character from the end c#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Sample `string`:

**A3148579**

Expected result:

**798514A3**

I tried this code:

```
 public static string Reverse(string s)
 {
     char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();

     Array.Reverse(charArray);

     return new string(charArray);
 }
```

the *actual* result is **9758413A**

but I want **798514A3**

[image]

thanks everyone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse string by 2 pair in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148706/reverse-string-by-2-pair-in-c-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the initial string into chunks of `size = 2` (e.g. with a help of `Substring`); note that `ToCharArray()` returns `char`s i.e. chunks of `size = 1`.

Let's generalize the solution: now we have `size` of chunks

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static string Reverse(string s, int size = 2) {
  if (size < 1)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    return s;
  
  int n = s.Length / size + (s.Length % size == 0 ? 0 : 1);

  return string.Concat(Enumerable
    .Range(0, n)
    .Select(i => i < n - 1 ? s.Substring(i * size, size) : s.Substring(i * size))
    .Reverse());
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.Write(Reverse("A3148579"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
798514A3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try below code. This is just to give you a idea and you can update based on the test cases and requirement. Below code works fine for your input which you have mentioned. I have not considered if the length is odd. You can do your research and update logic which will help you to learn and know more.

string input = "A3148579";
            Stack stack = new Stack();
            int count = 0;
            string output = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length/2; i++)
            {
                stack.Push(input.Substring(count, 2));
                count = count + 2;
            }

            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                output += stack.Pop().ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[C# Example: Split An Array into Multiple Smaller Arrays](https://jianmingli.com/wp/?p=11517)

Use Lambda expression to extends Array class to include a new method called Split:

```
public static class MyArrayExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Splits an array into several smaller arrays.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the array.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="array">The array to split.</param>
    /// <param name="size">The size of the smaller arrays.</param>
    /// <returns>An array containing smaller arrays.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this T[] array, int size)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < (float)array.Length / size; i++)
        {
            yield return array.Skip(i * size).Take(size);
        }
    }
}
```

Test the new array class method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSplit2()
{
   string str = "A3148579";

    char[] array1 = new char[str.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = i;
    }


    // Split into smaller arrays of maximal 2 elements
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> splited = array1.Split<int>(2);
    int j = 0;
    foreach (IEnumerable<int> s in splited){
        j++;
    }
    log.InfoFormat("Splitted in to {0} smaller arrays.", j);
}
```

Finally you just need to reverse the resulted array(smaller).